# Как сделать запуск игры с параметрами через ссылку в игровом лаунчере?

Tags: c#, css

Всем привет

Есть у меня лаунчер Майнкрафт с браузером внутри(WebBrowser)
Сделанный в visual studio

И через сайт который встроен в лаунчере
Я пытался сделать запуск игры с параметрами через ссылку

`<a href=“mylaunch:\\1.16.5:93.100.157:25565”>Play</a>`
mylaunch - мой лаунчер
1.16.5 это ID (у каждой версии свой ID, они скачиваются через versions.json)
IP&Port - параметры,при запуске должен сразу подключаться к серверу

Один из примеров того что я пытался использовать
Я перерыл все какие только возможно форумы
Но не нашёл ничего что может решить данный вопрос
Информация есть но она годов 10

Я смотрел как это сделано у других
Но ничего из этого не помогало решить данный вопрос

Как мне сделать запуск/установку игры с параметрами через ссылку?
Тоесть при нажатии на ссылку, через мой лаунчер должна запуститься игра

Comment: для начала добейся того что бы ты ввел в адрес браузера ссылку и твоя игра запустилась без всякого кода в вижуал студио. Если это ты найдешь то, что наверняка срабатывает, тогда приходи сюда с вопросом) А пока что ты просишь помощи у оракулов которые здесь не водятся.

Comment: лично мне непонятно даже банальный адрес. Что это? В конце что-то похоже на порт. А то что на начале даже не похоже на айпишник - там и чисел слишком много и двоеточие по центру. И что должен вообще делать майланч, что это? Все выглядит хренью, короче. И здесь просто не найдется человек в этом разбирающийся.

Comment: IP состоит из 4 цифр. Синтаксически ссылка может выглядеть правильно так `mylaunch:\\x.x.x.x:p?version=1.16.5` Кстати WebBrowser (IE 11) устарел, и его поддержка будет скоро прекращена в Windows. Используйте либо CefSharp (CEF), либо WebView2 (Edge).

Comment: Кстати, зачем вам вообще браузер в приложении? Почему бы не сделать нормальный интерфейс, например на WPF?